# constants in Python: at the root of the module or in a namespace inside the module?

Tags: python

I'm building a Python module with about a hundred constants.

I would like to avoid naming issues when people import my module so I was wondering what would be the best way to do it.

```
MY_CONSTANT = 1
MY_SECOND_CONSTANT = 2
...
MY2_CONSTANT = "a"
MY2_SECOND_CONSTANT = "b"
...
```

Or

```
class My:
  CONSTANT = 1
  SECOND_CONSTANT = 2
  ...

class My2
  CONSTANT = "a"
  SECOND_CONSTANT = "b"
  ...
```

Or maybe another of your suggestions?

Coming from Java, I surely prefer the second way, but some might find it overkill...

Comment: According to selected answer below, I would also have to split my module into `my.py` and `my2.py`, having `CONSTANT` and `SECOND_CONSTANT` in each of them.

Comment: "at the root of the module or in a namespace inside the module?": Yes. ;-)

Comment: Yes.  `my.CONSTANT` and `my.SECOND_CONSTANT` look quite nice, don't they?  No silly `MY_` or MY2_` making the names look bad.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Well, it depends. Usually, constants are defined at module level. But if you have many constants for `category_a` and `category_b`, it might even make sense to add a subpackage `constants` with modules `constants.category_a` and `constants.category_b`.

I would refrain from using a `class` - it could be instantiated, which wouldn't make sense, and it has no advantage over a module, apart from allowing you to cram more than one into one physical file (which you probably shouldn't do if there are so many constants). The Java version would probably use a static class, but the Python equivalent is a module.

Name clashes aren't an issue in Python except when you `import *` (but you shouldn't do that anyways: [according to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/doanddont.html)). As long as there are no name clashes inside the module, rest assured that the user will neither pull out all the names from your module into his own, nor import it under a name that clashes with another module.

Comment: Completely answers the full question I had. Just a remark about Java: in that case, you would write a final class with final static members, not a static class, but I'm digressing.

Comment: I do have a question about this: are these constants modifiable? Can I say: `constants.CONSTANT = 'my_value'` or is there some implicit read-onlyness here?

Comment: Your "but you shouldn't do that anyway" link is broken. I suppose the correct link is https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/doanddont.html

Answer (score 37):

Every module provides its own namespace, so there's no need to create another one.

Having module `foo.py`:

```
FOO = 1
BAR = 2
SHMOO = 3
```

you may use it like this:

```
import foo
foo.BAR
```

Answer (score 21):

From [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#constants):

> #### Constants
>
> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include `MAX_OVERFLOW` and `TOTAL`.

Answer (score 6):

If you use classes you can forbid overwrite of constants (or forbid even adding constants to that class). Also advantage of using class over files(modules) is when you have many groups you need not to have many files.

So it would look like this:

```
class MyConstBaseClass: 
    """
    forbids to overwrite existing variables 
    forbids to add new values if "locked" variable exists
    """ 
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if(self.__dict__.has_key("locked")):    
            raise NameError("Class is locked can not add any attributes (%s)"%name)
        if self.__dict__.has_key(name):
            raise NameError("Can't rebind const(%s)"%name)
        self.__dict__[name]=value

class MY_CONST_GRP1(MyConstBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.const1 = "g1c1"
        self.const2 = "g1c2"
my_const_grp1 = MY_CONST_GRP1()

class MY_CONST_GRP2(MyConstBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.const1 = "g2c1"
        self.const3 = "g2c3"
        self.locked = 1 # this will create lock for adding constants 
my_const_grp2 = MY_CONST_GRP2()

print my_const_grp1.const1 # prints "g1c1" 
print my_const_grp1.const2 # prints "g1c2"
print my_const_grp2.const1 # prints "g2c1"
print my_const_grp2.const3 # prints "g2c3"
my_const_grp1.new_constant = "new value" #adding constants is allowed to this group
#my_const_grp1.const1 = "new value" #redefine would raise an error
#my_const_grp2.new_constant = "first value" #adding constant is also forbidden
#my_const_grp2.const1 = "new value" #redefine would raise an error
```

[Here is simillar example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/?in=user-97991)

Comment: Why not add `const1` and `const2` at the `class` level instead of the `self` level?

Comment: @ScottP. They are at "class" level, if by that you mean "inside the class" and not "at the same level as the class, so global". There is no "self" level. The `self.` is the way a member function accesses the class members.

Comment: @Law29

At the root / zero column is module level.
After `class` but not inside `__init__(self)` is class level.

Comment: This may be useful in certain specific use cases, but for the overwhelming majority of cases I would recommend using modules